# Android :How to get updated time after 2 seconds without using Thread.sleep

Tags: java, android, time

I need to know can we get time updated after every two seconds without making the thread sleep . 
I'm getting time from this code 
as i need to put it somewhere after 2 seconds

```
_hours = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        secondForAnother = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        _minutes = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Comment: Wrap the logic in a `Runnable` and post it to a `Handler` with a 2 second delay?

Comment: bad code. rewrite it. Imagine situation when this code runs at 15:59:59. you got hour - 15, second - 59 and at that point clock ticked  (time is 16:00:00) and you can minute as 00 - result will be 15:00:59.

Comment: i want to put This updated time in the multiplerender of achartenine  for x axis labels in graph